# Office 365 Authentication with Microsoft Graph

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, exchangewebservices

I previously used the following code for authentication on my application web server using a token obtained from Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync in my 365 client add-in:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
service.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(token);
service.Url = new Uri(ewsUrl);
```

I am now trying to convert my EWS server code to Microsoft Graph, but I'm having trouble getting access to those APIs using that 365 token.  I've tried something like this but to no avail:

```
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
                {
                    requestMessage
                        .Headers
                        .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);

                    return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
                }));
```

My Permissions in Azure should be okay as I've already been able to obtain various items and save into the system. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Graph and EWS have different audiences in their tokens, you cannot mix the two.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  What about if using options.isRest = true in the Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync method call?  Basically I'm asking if there is any way to use the Graph APIs in conjunction with an Office 365 Add-In.  Thanks again.